# Would time travel be useful for optimization?

Tags: programming-languages, operating-systems

Let's say we have circuitry that can send pieces of data to the past state of the program through literal time travel. Said time travel takes 1-5 clock cycles (I cannot assume the nature of time travel so I am giving slight lee-way) and sends one byte to some byte in the past programs memory along with a check bit to some other location so that the time travel can be detected. The general purpose would be for the program to basically run once and then essentially bootstrap paradoxing the original calculation, thereby in essence only taking the amount of time it took to send the data back to the program's past state.

Would it actually be realistic for a user level  or utility program to use this as a fast/cheap way to optimize a program? My guess is that it is only good for extremely complex calculations such as prime number searches, framebuffer generations for 3D graphics, etc. but I cannot be entirely sure.

Assuming this were in the C language, the syntax for code to be bootstrapped would look like this (in case one wishes to write examples of cases they find contradictory)

```
bootstrap (<checkbit to see if time travel has occurred>)
{
    <code to process and create the original data>

    send: <list of addresses to be sent back separated by commas>
    to: <list of addresses of where the data should be sent to separated by commas>
}
```

Assume energy/radiation/side effects of time travel are irrelevant. This assumes that it is literally as easy to time travel as it is to run an adding circuit. Also, assume that people have worked out all the "bugs" from the system. The circuit works correctly without fail.

***I apologize if this is the wrong stack exchange site. I wish to speak scientifically regarding this in a real theoretical sense and this seemed like the more theoretical CS stack exchange site.***

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say that you're assuming that the time travel instructions are as cheap and reliable as any classical instruction. So why wouldn't they be a viable optimization strategy? Any calculation that takes more than a couple of clock cycles can be performed "in the future" and the answer time-travelled back.

Comment: @DavidRicherby because as I said, it would require requesting the data from the operating system.

Comment: And the OS is using this optimization, too, surely? So when I request data from the operating system, it's already there.

Comment: @DavidRicherby that may be true but no matter what the request still has to be made to the Os at some point as the data must be sent back.

Comment: This question sounds too hypothetical/speculative to me.  It invents an implausible situation, with artificial restrictions that neither make it more interesting nor more plausible.  Asking about the computational consequences of time travel sounds implausible but interesting.  But then adding in the restriction that (for some unstated reason) this time travel can only be done through the OS?  I can't see any reason why such a restriction would exist.  That sounds like just making stuff up, with no basis.

Comment: @D.W. because only the OS can know the true physical location of memory so the OS would have to handle where to place the memory. If that is a wrong assumption then feel free to post an argument countering that assumption. It was merely my opinion of where such a thing would logically fit into the software architecture.

Comment: It's not true that only the OS can know the true physical location of memory.  It's possible to run software that knows the physical location of its own memory (e.g., if it runs on the bare metal or with no OS or with paging disabled or a number of other situations).  I suggest the question would be more interesting if you just asked what the computational consequences of time travel are, without drawing in your assumptions about the OS.

Comment: I was referring to it being used like on Windows or something where the memory mapping unit is used to find the address. But fair enough. I'll remove that. I suppose that will just be a particular situation one thinks of anyway. :)

Comment: It is very hypothetical (interesting though), but I do not see any valid reason to assume the time traveling part exists and we are still using current solutions. Also if I understood correctly it would be benefitial everywhere, since it is cheap and easy to use every operation taking more than said 5 cycles could transfer data back to make it immediately available. If you read from disk to future RAM and send the data back then the cost of reading from disk is 5 cycles, so why not loop everywhere?

Comment: @Evil because maybe we want to control how and where we can send data back? :p

Comment: Optimization seems like a rather narrow scope, if we can send back information to the past, nearly every human process on the earth that produces information would use this technology . Telemarketers would make a sale with every call, until no person they could sell to remains. Targeted ads would only target those who end up clicking them. Your barista would hand you your drink before you can order it.

Comment: @KurtMueller good point. However, doing it on a longer timescale might be more risky at times. If the system goes down you lose x amount of minutes wasting time. At a computer level, if the system crashes its no different that a regular program crashing. I dont think people would want to rely on such technology that deeply. Great point though!

Comment: I think people would. In terms of reliability, there's a lot of engineering you could do with redundancy, with the cloud, etc, to make sure the message gets sent back. And I think the rewards are undeniable: the first person to wield this technology would singlehandedly rule the financial markets, not to mention winning every bet at the casino. Oil discovery would be much cheaper since companies can send themselves a message back saying where they found oil in the past year. Almost every industry has enormous consequences

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  If time travel were possible, it would be a huge win for optimization and computation: it would enable us to solve computational problems that today seem very hard to solve with existing computers.

To formalize this, we must first agree on a model of physics that allows time travel and that describes what happens when you try.  There are various plausible ways to do that.  Under one plausible set of assumptions about the physics, the set of problems you can solve in polynomial time using time travel is all of [PSPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE).  (If you're not familiar with it, PSPACE is the set of problems solvable by classical no-time-travel computers in  any amount of running time you want, subject only the restriction that the space usage must be polynomial.)  For instance, every problem in NP could be solved in polynomial time if time travel were possible.

For instance, there are problems that today seem to require exponential time to solve (with classical no-time-travel computers), but could be solved in polynomial time if time travel were possible.

To learn more about this subject, I suggest you take a look at Scott Aaronson's lecture notes: http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec19.html

Comment: Woah. That is an awesome paper!